# time format in access 2007 - need help

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have this value in date field: `07/09/2010 07:34`

how i can see this only: `07:34`

how to do it in access 2007 and in C# format ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date dt = <value>;
String time = dt.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Use HH:mm for 24 hour format and hh:mm tt for 12 hour format with AM/PM.

Use this for reference:
http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/demos/datetimeformats.aspx

Comment: As in `SELECT Format([DateAndTime],"Short Time") AS TimeOnly
FROM SomeTable` ?